# Use PHP variable in Vuejs component

Tags: php, wordpress, vuejs2

I work on some custom code for Wordpress, and I need to access some PHP variables with Vuejs.
Right now I can't access PHP variables, also I get an error, and I am not sure what is wrong (error on data).

```
<?php
function nrc_new_modalities(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  
    $multipleSelect2 =  get_user_meta( $user_id, 'multipleSelect2', true );
    $multipleSelect2 = isset( $multipleSelect2 ) ? $multipleSelect2 : array();
  
    $modality_list    = get_terms([
      'taxonomy'    => 'product_cat',
      'hide_empty'  => false,
      'parent'      => 92
  ]);
?>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{modality_list}}</p> //Here I get plain text
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.8/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() { // Here I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'"
            return {
                modality_list: <?php json_encode($modality_list) ?>,
            }
        },
        created(){
            var new_val = <?php json_encode($modality_list) ?>
            console.log('Val:', new_val)  //here I get NULL
        }
    });
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you give some more details?

Comment: Vue doesn't work like that, you need to make a component and pass it as a prop when you call the component.

Comment: Actually it works, I had to add <?php echo  json_encode($modality_list); ?> , no errors and works fine.